# How to bind lists like an updating ForEach?

Tags: javafx, binding, javafx-2

Here is a sample code:

```
public class Example3 {

    class Point {
        int x, y; // these can be properties if it matters
    }

    class PointRepresentation {
        Point point; // this can be a property if it matters

        public PointRepresentation(Point point) {
            this.point = point;
        }
    }

    Example3() {
        ObservableList<Point> points = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<PointRepresentation> representations = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        points.forEach(point -> representations.add(new PointRepresentation(point)));
    }
}
```

I have a data holder `Point` and a data representor `PointRepresentation`. I have a list of points and i would like that for each point in the list there would be an equivalent representation object in the second list. The code I gave works for the initialization but if there is any change later the above will not update.

What I am doing now is using a change listener to synchronize the lists (add and remove elements based on the change object) and it's OK but i am wondering if there's a simpler solution. I was looking for something like a "for each bind" that means: for each element in one list there is one in the other with the specified relation between them [in my case its that constructor]. In pseudocode:

```
representations.bindForEach(points, point -> new PointRepresentation(point));
```

Things I looked at: extractors for the list but that sends updates when a property in the objects they hold change and not when the list itself changes. So in my case if `x` in the point changes i can make an extractor that notifies it. Another thing I looked at is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/ListBinding.html, so maybe a custom binding does it but I don't know if it's simpler.

Also is there a similar solution for arrays instead of lists? i saw the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableArray.html as a possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third-party library [ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX) has functionality for this. You can do

```
ObservableList<Point> points = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ObservableList<PointRepresentation> representations = LiveList.map(points, PointRepresentation::new);
```

This will update `representations` automatically on add/remove etc changes to `points`.

Comment: `LiveList.map` looks exactly like what I meant with `bindForEach`. great. Is there something like this for arrays?

Comment: @Mark I don't believe there is anything similar for arrays. You can't `add` or `remove` from an array anyway.

Comment: OK. i was looking at [ObservableArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/toc.htm). It seems very undeveloped. Only 2 primitive are supported and whatever "Face" is it copies the javadoc of Integer.